# Which Mobile Suits from the anime were designed by Hajime Katoki?

Tags: gundam

I love the look of the "Ver. Ka" Master Grade model kits. I know he was the lead designer for V and Endless Waltz. He also worked on 0083, Wing, and G among others.  I would like to know which specific Mobile Suits he designed from the Gundam anime franchises.

Comment: Are you referring to just gunpla or Gundam mech design in general?

Comment: @Krazer Specifically from the anime.  It's pretty easy to tell which gunpla models where redone by him from the "ver. KA" they tend to stick on the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you're looking for original designs and no redesigns.

He worked on the Gundam 0083 OVA series, where he designed the famous [RX-78 GP03 Dendrobium Orchis](http://www.mahq.net/mecha/gundam/0083/rx-78gp03.htm) mobile weapon.

He also did a lot of work in V Gundam, where he was the main mechanical designer, creating the main mobile suits:

- [Victory Gundam](http://www.mahq.net/mecha/gundam/v/lm312v04.htm)
- [V2 Gundam](http://mahq.net/mecha/gundam/v/lm314v21.htm)
- [V2 Assault Buster Gundam](http://www.mahq.net/mecha/gundam/v/lm314v23-24.htm)

After that, he worked on G Gundam, designing the evil mobile suits.

He also worked on *Gundam Wing*, doing some some minor mobile suits, but his mostnotable contrtibution is to *Gundam Wing Endless Waltz*, where he designed all of the mobile suits, and re-designed the Gundams in a more fantastic style, the most famous of which is the [XXXG-00W0 Wing Gundam Zero Custom](http://www.mahq.net/mecha/gundam/endlesswaltz/xxxg-00w0.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Hajime Katoki done a boat load of Mecha design's for a ton of different series. You should check out his wiki page [Hajime Katoki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hajime_Katoki) where I believe all of his credited works are listed, and the series for which he made them.

Just to list a few he worked on

- Master Grade

  - RX-78-2 Gundam Ver.Ka
  - XXXG-01W Wing Gundam Ver.Ka
  - RB-79 Ball Ver.Ka
  - XM-X1 Crossbone Gundam X-1 Ver.Ka
  - RX-0 Unicorn Gundam Ver.Ka
  - MSN-06S Sinanju Ver. Ka
  - LM312V04 Victory Gundam Ver. Ka
  - RX-93 Nu Gundam Ver. Ka

> Born in 1963, Katoki created designs for the graphic novel Gundam Sentinel. He then worked in the OVA series Gundam 0083, where he designed the RX-78 GP03 Dendrobium Orchis mobile weaponHis next big work was V Gundam, where he was the main mechanical designercreating the main mobile suits Victory Gundam, V2 Gundam and the V2 Assault Buster Gundam. After that, he worked in G Gundam, now in design of the evil mobile suits. He then worked in Gundam Wing on some minor mobile suits, but in Gundam Wing Endless Waltz he designed all of the mobile suits, and re-designed the Gundams with a more fantastic style, creating the XXXG-00W0 Wing Gundam Zero Custom. To correspond with these new designs, he also redesigned the 5 original Gundams from Gundam Wing.

Comment: The op is asking for anime mecha designs, instead of gunpla models, which is extra-canonical to their respective series.